# Define ElasticsearchIntegrationTest client in the test context xml

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, integration-testing, spring-data-elasticsearch

In our application we are integrating ES.
There is a repository with an ElasticsearchTemplate injected:

```
@Repository
public class ElasticSearchRepositoryImpl implements ElasticSearchRepository {
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;
    @Autowired
        public ElasticSearchRepositoryImpl(ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate){
            this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
        }
```

In the tests side, we are making use of the [ElasticsearchIntegrationTest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html#integration-tests) class as defined in the documentation. 
The tests have their own context, but since the repository is being annotated with the `@Repository` annotation, it is being loaded and this makes me define an `ElasticsearchTemplate` in the test context.
At this point, I dont want to define a template, because if so I would need to define a client and since I am going to use in the tests the `client()` provided by the `ElasticsearchIntegrationTest`, this would make no sense.
I have different possibilities:

1. Exclude in the test context the repository - this is being used by other beans and I would have to exclude many things and deal with a lot of problems, besides I don't think is clean.
2. Declare the template with no client (I don't like this possibility either):
3. Use the client provided by the `ElasticsearchIntegrationTest` in the template definition within the test context - I don't know how to do this, any hint would be welcome.

Any other solution, example or idea that helps me would be very welcome.
Thanks in advance

For my solution 2 I post here my code, could not post it above:

```
<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client"><null /></constructor-arg><!-- TODO: this client should be manually injected in the tests -->
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Spring Application, the easiest way to create an integration test with Elasticsearch is to instanciate an embedded node.

```
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    // create and start an ES node
    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.builder()
                .put("path.data", "target/data")
                .build();

        Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().local(true).settings(settings).node();
        return node.client();
    }

    // initialize your ES template
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
    }

}
```

If you use Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch, it will create an embedded node automatically when any configuration is provided.